# Override reverse SharedElementTransition when onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, onbackpressed, shared-element-transition

I have 4 `ImageButton`s placed in a simple `Layout`. When I click any of these buttons, a new `TabActivity` is launched, and the corresponding `Tab` is selected (0-3). The tabs are styled with an `ImageView` matching one of the previous buttons each.

**EDIT WITH SOME PROGRESS BELOW**

**TL;DR:** *How to set a different SharedElementTransition when returning to the calling Activity, so that the "back" transition is not a reverse of the original one, and possibly animate different `View`s?*

I also use a SharedElementTransition to animate the ImageButton into the selected tab, which works when entering the new `Activity`, but if I navigate through the `Fragment`s of the new `Activity`, and press the back button from a `Fragment` different from the one I arrived to, the reverse SharedElementTransition doesn't match the `Tab` I'm currently on, and it just reverses the transition used to launch the new activity.

I can see this is the expected behavior, but how can I override it? I want the reverse transition to start from the current `Tab`, not from the `Tab` I arrived at from the previous `Activity`.

I hope this ignominious picture helps understanding the question (it shows the behavior I want to obtain -starting new activity from the orange button, navigating to the green tab's fragment, and pressing back returning to the first activity transitioning from the green tab-):
[image: Back transition problem]

There's no much code involved in the question, but just in case I am launching the new `Activity` as:

```
(...)
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(fromActivity, sharedView, transitionName);
fromActivity.startActivityForResult(toIntent, requestCode, options.toBundle());
```

And then, in the arriving `Activity`, I set up the `TabLayout` as follows in the `onCreate()` method (analogous piece of code for each `Tab`:

```
tab0 = (...);
ImageView v0 = (ImageView) tab0.findViewById(R.id.tab_img);
ApiLevelHelper.setImageDrawable(this, v0, R.drawable.menu_btn_0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab0);
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT - SOME PROGRESS ACHIEVED**

Well, There's still an important problem to solve, but I've managed to get the right `Tab` transitioning on the reverse animation. In order to achieve this, I have no transition name previously attached to the `Tab`'s `ImageView`s, and I set the transition name on the `onCreate()` method of the new activity only to the selected `Tab`. Then inside the `onBackPressed()` call, I clear all transition names from all `Tab`'s `ImageView`s, and set it to the current `Tab`. This way the reverse animation starts from the correct `Tab`, but it ends up in the original `ImageView`'s position, instead of the new one.

What I've tried so far:

1. Clearing transition names on the first activity and setting it just to the ImageView I want to reverse-transition to, inside the `onActivityResult(...)` method. Sadly enough, the animation conditions seem to be stablished before this method is called.
2. Staticly referencing the parent activity (knowing this is bad, just testing) and clearing transition names and setting just the one I want before calling `super.onBackPressed()` from the second `Activity`. It didn't change anything.

Some code showing how the transition name of the current `Tab` is set:

```
//Second Activity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (ApiLevelHelper.isAtLeast(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)) {
        for (ImageView v : tabImages) {
            v.setTransitionName(null);
        }
        int selectedTab = mTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
        tabImages[selectedTab].setTransitionName(getString(R.string.transition_menu_tab));
        Intent output = new Intent();
        output.putExtra("selected_tab", selectedTab);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And then, in the first `Activity`...:

```
//First Activity
//This code has no effect right now on the ending position of the transitioned view.
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_WHICH_TAB && data != null) {
        if (ApiLevelHelper.isAtLeast(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)) {
            int selectedTab = data.getIntExtra("selected_tab", 0);
            setTransitionName(selectedTab); //This call nullifies all transition names 
                                            //and sets it back to the right ImageView. 
                                            //But it doesn't work.
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I think I somehow need to manipulate the previously calculated transform... still investigating.